# JWPlayer time seek area and reset vars

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jwplayer, seek

The goal is to create a video player that is only playable thru outside events, which is a click.  The click event contains a data attr that specifies the area to play, i.e... 10 seconds thru 25 seconds.

Multiple buttons exists.  After each time is lapsed, it needs to pause the video.

the buttons sequence will appear in random order.

Heres the example code:
http://jsfiddle.net/arkjoseph/n2rpq1t4/28/

```
    <div id="player"></div>


<section>
    <div class="seeker" data-start="0" data-end="5">Go to 0-5</div>
</section>
<section>
    <div class="seeker" data-start="6" data-end="10">Go to 6-10</div>
</section>



$(function(){

    $("section").each(function(){
        $(this).find(".seeker").on('click',function(event){
            var start = $(this).data('start'),
                end   = $(this).data('end');
            seekitnow(start,end);              
        });
    }); 
});

function seekitnow(start,end) {
    jwplayer("player").seek(start).onTime(function(event) {
        var start;
        if(event.position >= end) {
            this.pause();
        }
        //var end;
     });
   }
```

The works to a degree but each button click is registering the existing variable that was stored(start / end). How can I prevent this from happening?

If i click button 1 (0-5) it works fine.  If i click 6-10, the video stops and the console has 0,5,6,10.

HELP!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I debugged this a little to try and figure out exactly what the odd behaviour was.

I noticed that the every time the `Go to 0-5` and `Go to 6-10` sections were clicked, `jwPlayer.onTime()` was being called along with the creation of new jwPlayer handlers (`jwplayer("player").seek(start).onTime(function(event) {`), which resulted in new callbacks being added to the queue of callbacks for the jwPlayer time change event.

This was causing a lot of strange behaviour as I continued clicking the sections.

I changed the code around so that `onTime()` is only executed once and that the `end` is shared state, and then forked the jsFiddle.

The resulting behavior is:

- When clicking on `Go to 0-5`, the video seeks to time `0`, and pauses
  when second `5` is reached.
- When clicking on `Go to 6-10`, the video
  seeks to second `5`, and pauses when second `10` is reached.

Is this the correct behavior?: https://jsfiddle.net/a8dao9d4/

```
jwplayer("player").setup({
    file: "https://player.vimeo.com/external/135492851.hd.mp4?s=a61836463fbde188aaa1e24e6bfeeb39&profile_id=113",
    startparam: "starttime",
});

$(function(){

    var player = jwplayer("player");
    var end = 32;

    player.onTime(function(event) {
        if(event.position >= end) {
            this.pause();
        }
    });

    $("section").each(function(){
        $(this).find(".seeker").on('click',function(event){
            end = $(this).data('end');

            player.seek(
                $(this).data('start')
            );
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining your debugging process.  I didn't know onTime could be used in this manner.

Comment: Good answer! Thanks for sharing this.